# Convert a dict to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

My data look like this :

```
{u'"57e01311817bc367c030b390"': u'{"ad_since": 2016, "indoor_swimming_pool": "No", "seaside": "No", "handicapped_access": "Yes"}', u'"57e01311817bc367c030b3a8"': u'{"ad_since": 2012, "indoor_swimming_pool": "No", "seaside": "No", "handicapped_access": "Yes"}'}
```

I want to convert it to a pandas Dataframe. But when I try

```
df = pd.DataFrame(response.items())
```

I get a DataFrame with two columns, the first with the first key, and the second with the values of the key:

```
                            0                       1 
0  "57e01311817bc367c030b390"   {"ad_since": 2016, "indoor_swimming_pool": "No...
1  "57e01311817bc367c030b3a8"   {"ad_since": 2012, "indoor_swimming_pool": "No...
```

How can I get a single column for each key : `"ad_since"`, `"indoor_swimming_pool"`, `"indoor_swimming_pool"` ? And keep the first column, or get the id as index.

Comment: Try read_json http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: Do you try your sample data with `pd.DataFrame(response.items())` ? For me it doesnt work.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the comment, I edited my post

Comment: @RichardRublev I tried it, but got the error `TypeError: Expected String or Unicode`

Comment: @mitsi - thank you. but I think two records were nice, but now there is only one record - second row in DataFrame is missing. Can you add some [valid](http://jsonlint.com/) json or list of json?

Comment: @jezrael it's now done with both rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need convert column of `type` `str` to `dict` by `.apply(literal_eval)` or `.apply(json.loads)` and then use [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

response = {u'"57e01311817bc367c030b390"': u'{"ad_since": 2016, "indoor_swimming_pool": "No", "seaside": "No", "handicapped_access": "Yes"}', 
           u'"57e01311817bc367c030b3a8"': u'{"ad_since": 2012, "indoor_swimming_pool": "No", "seaside": "No", "handicapped_access": "Yes"}'}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response, orient='index')

print (type(df.iloc[0,0]))
<class 'str'>

df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].apply(literal_eval)

print (pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.iloc[:,0].values.tolist(), index=df.index))
                            ad_since handicapped_access indoor_swimming_pool  \
"57e01311817bc367c030b3a8"      2012                Yes                   No   
"57e01311817bc367c030b390"      2016                Yes                   No   

                           seaside  
"57e01311817bc367c030b3a8"      No  
"57e01311817bc367c030b390"      No
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import json

response = {u'"57e01311817bc367c030b390"': u'{"ad_since": 2016, "indoor_swimming_pool": "No", "seaside": "No", "handicapped_access": "Yes"}', 
           u'"57e01311817bc367c030b3a8"': u'{"ad_since": 2012, "indoor_swimming_pool": "No", "seaside": "No", "handicapped_access": "Yes"}'}


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response, orient='index')
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].apply(json.loads)


print (pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.iloc[:,0].values.tolist(), index=df.index))
                            ad_since handicapped_access indoor_swimming_pool  \
"57e01311817bc367c030b3a8"      2012                Yes                   No   
"57e01311817bc367c030b390"      2016                Yes                   No   

                           seaside  
"57e01311817bc367c030b3a8"      No  
"57e01311817bc367c030b390"      No
```

Comment: With the first method (with `literal_eval`) and the entire data set I got the error `ValueError: malformed string` its probably because of special characters. But it works perfectly with the second method with `json.loads`, thank you

Comment: Glad can help you.

Answer (score 1):

As the values are strings, you can use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and list comprehension:

```
In [20]: d =     {u'"57e01311817bc367c030b390"': u'{"ad_since": 2016, "indoor_swimming_pool": "No", "seaside": "No", "handicapped_access": "Yes"}', u'"57e01311817bc367c030b3a8"': u'{"ad_since": 2012, "indoor_swimming_pool": "No", "seaside": "No", "handicapped_access": "Yes"}'}

In [21]: import json

In [22]: pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, [json.loads(e)[k] for e in d.values()]) for k in json.loads(d.values()[0])]), index=d.keys())Out[22]: 
                            ad_since handicapped_access indoor_swimming_pool  \
"57e01311817bc367c030b390"      2016                Yes                   No   
"57e01311817bc367c030b3a8"      2012                Yes                   No   

                       seaside  
"57e01311817bc367c030b390"      No  
"57e01311817bc367c030b3a8"      No
```